# Why does using a jQuery object as parameter in html() work?

Tags: jquery

I recently discovered quite by accident that using a jQuery object as a parameter in of `html()` works.  Accordin to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2), the only acceptable types are `htmlString` and `function` but for some reason the following still works:

```js
var htmlString = '<span>hello world</span>';
var jQueryObject = $(htmlString);
$('div').html(jQueryObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Seems the mechanics of my snippet might have been misconstrued, so offering this to help clarify.  The `html()` will successfully take ***any*** jQuery object - regardless how it's constructed.  You can see below that I'm simply selecting the `<span>` element in the top div and moving it. In this case no `htmlString` is ever introduced.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#fill-me').html($('#move-me span'));
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#move-me {
  color: red;
}

#fill-me {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="move-me"><span>Hello World</span></div>
<div id="fill-me"></div>
<button>Click to Move HTML</button>
```

Why does this work counter to what the docs say is supported?  Did I miss something in the documentation?

Comment: Per the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString): _"A string is designated htmlString in jQuery documentation when it is used to represent one or more DOM elements, typically to be created and inserted in the document. When passed as an argument of the jQuery() function, the string is identified as HTML if it starts with <tag ... >) and is parsed as such until the final > character."_

Comment: @j08691 His question is about `.html(jQueryObject`, not about `$(htmlString)`

Comment: @Barmar His question as about why `.html()` is accepting the jQuery object when the docs state is accepts a `htmlString` and I am showing the documentation about how jQuery views a `htmlString`

Comment: And where does that say that a jQuery object can be used as an HTML string?

Comment: @j08691 `htmlString` is an HTML string, but `jQueryObject` isn't.

Comment: @j08691 -  I'm pretty clear on how `htmlString` is defined and sorry if I'm not understand but how is that relevant to this question?

Comment: You're asking why when you pass a jQuery object (`var jQueryObject = $(htmlString);`) to the `.html()` function it works when the `.html()` docs say that it only accepts `htmlString` and `function`, correct? My point is that the jQuery docs for `htmlString` state _When passed as an argument of the jQuery() function, the string is identified as HTML if it starts with <tag ... >) and is parsed as such until the final > character._ So jQuery identifies your string `'<span>hello world</span>'`, even though in a jQuery object, as an `htmlString` by definition.

Comment: You can pass any jQuery object - even something like `$('#myDivID')` as an argument to `html()` and it works.  The snippet above is only an example where I've constructed something from scratch.

Comment: @j08691 - please see updated snippet in question to clarify.  There is no `htmlString` at all in the new snippet and yet it still works.  I think this pretty clearly demonstrates the behaviour in question.

Comment: If you're continuing to message me in the hopes of removing the downvote on your question, sorry, I can't help you, it wasn't me. Also you accepted an answer so I'm not sure why you need anything else from me.

Comment: Thanks - I am only trying to clarify since it seemed like you weren't understanding. Hope this makes it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the jQuery source code, it implements the following logic (I've simplified a bit):

```
if (typeof value == 'string') {
    // assign the value to .innerHTML
} else {
    this.empty().append(value);
}
```

So you can give `.html()` anything that's acceptable to `.append()`, and `.append()` can take a jQuery object.

This isn't an officially acceptable parameter type, it's simply an accident of implementation. There's no guarantee that it will continue to work in future versions. If you want to put a jQuery object in an element, use `.append()`:

```
$('div').empty().append(jQueryObject);
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  It seems to me if the documentation is going to the trouble of declaring the acceptable parameter types, that it should be thorough enough to note this.  I'll file a bug.

Comment: It's not an officially acceptable parameter type, it just happens to work.

Comment: After reviewing the source, I agree - but for a robust library that's as widely used as jQuery, it irks me when things "just happen to work".  Seems sloppy

Comment: Sorry, but jQuery is full of stuff like this. There's lots of undocumented features.